# What is the latest version of Mono that can be run on Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: mono, raspberry-pi2

I am currently working from Mono Version 3.2.8 and am running into trouble finding any documentation on this version. I have no idea what code will run until after I get the exceptions. Either a compatibility list to what works or an idea of what version I can compile that works would be great. Any one have experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually install the latest version. I was easily able to install

*Mono version 4.6.2* on Raspbian.

The http://www.mono-project.com/docs/ site gives a general answer for which major libraries work. Letting you know when there isn't full compatibility but doesn't give specifics.